# Custom Size Winjs Listview Items Winjs WP

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winjs

I am new to Winjs, previously worked on Android and iOS development.

I need to make a listview with custom sized items as shown in http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview:customlayout
I have implemented this but in my windows phone the basic listitem size remain same, only the content size gets different. Follow the screen shot for visuals:
[image]

Can anybody tell me how can this be achieved. I have studied cell spaining also. But couldn't understand  it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Basically they have 2 item templates, based on your requirement you can create function to switch your templates for the list view.. What is it that is not working for you??

Comment: I don't exactly know. I am following the samples and http://try.buildwinjs.com/. I have developed the custom sized items but as you see in image the content only is getting resized not the whole item itself.

Comment: Could you please post the code for your templates?

Comment: Have you implemented the [itemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700705.aspx) function for your ListView?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an itemTemplate like this:

```
<div id="lstTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item">

        <img class="image" src="/images/Store.png" />

        <p class="lblName" data-win-bind="textContent:Name"></p>

        <p class="lblPrice" data-win-bind="textContent:Price"></p>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="lstMain"
                 class="lstContainer"
                 data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                 data-win-options="{
                 itemDataSource:DataFinal.listItems.dataSource,
                 itemTemplate:select('#lstTemplate'),
                 layout:{type:WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}">
 </div>
```

and then with CSS you can format the height of the item like this:

```
.fragmentPrincipal .lstContainer .item {
   height: 21.6875em;
}
```

Note: Remember to add a namespace class to you CSS, so your styles are not overridden once you navigated to another page

If you are targeting all windows phone resolutions I recommend that you use less in order to easily add the landscape and portrait style, also remember to scale all the images so you app can be rendered correctly on all WP resolutions